# Detecting page down and page up key presses in a Load all subfile

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

An additional requirement has come up for a load all subfile that I created. The subfile control record format has few input fields which are validated when the user presses Enter. Then if the input parameters are found to be valid, records from a database file satisfying the input parameter values are displayed as the subfile records.

The new requirement is that, if the user presses page down or page up after changing the input field values but without pressing Enter, the input field values should be revalidated and the subfile records refreshed as per the new parameters supplied.

Is this technically possible? As the subfile is a load all one, the page up or page down key presses will not pass control back to the program as the paging is handled by the OS.Hence I cannot see a way how the parameters can be revalidated. Is there a way to pass control back to the RPG when Page up or Page down is pressed and at the same time,l make the OS control the paging?

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: You should be doing page at a time for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the program would not get control back until the user paged all the way to the beginning or end of the subfile in an extendable subfile (SFLSIZE <> SFLPAGE). But if you used a page at a time subfile (SFLSIZE = SFLPAGE) then you can return control to the program for every PAGEUP/PAGEDOWN key press. This will change the structure of your program a bit, but you should be able to get it to work without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks Murph! I was looking for a confirmation before pushing this requirement back to my lead as one of the requirements in the Tech Spec was "Let the OS control the paging". Now I have the confidence.

Comment: But it would still be interesting if someone can find a sneaky way to let the control go back to the program if page down or page up is pressed but without having to include the ROLLUP or ROLLDOWN keywords in the DSPF DDS (i.e fool the OS into doing the paging for us).

Comment: You can think of it as the OS isn't doing the paging, the terminal is. You don't have a way to break into the terminal from the program, all you can do is send a buffer and wait for a response. this is very much like HTML with no programming capability at the client. HTML sends out a list, and the user can then scroll around the page, but to get the next page of stuff  they have to click the navigator. In our case the navigator is the page down key (once the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom of the subfile). There is no other way for the program to communicate with the terminal.

Comment: You could consider doing an auto enter on the last input field via `CHECK(ER)` assuming that the filed is completly filled.  `CHECK(FE)` may  be of interest also.